# Rails belongs_to STI table with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, sti

I've a STI table "parties" as follows:

```
# app/models/party.rb
class Party < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :party_contacts

  scope :vendors, -> { where(type: 'Party::Vendor') }
  scope :customers, -> { where(type: 'Party::Customer') }
end

# app/models/party/vendor.rb
class Party::Vendor < Party
end

# app/models/party/customer.rb
class Party::Customer < Party
end
```

And "party_contacts" table as follow:

```
class PartyContact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :party

  scope :of_vendors, -> {# fetch all contacts belongs to all vendors logic }
  scope :of_customers, -> {# fetch all contacts belongs to all customers logic }
end
```

I want to make query on "party_contacts" to get list of all vendors/customers contacts. How can I write the scope for "party_contacts" (or should it be in parent model)?

I'm trying following scopes:

```
scope :of_vendors, -> { joins(:party).includes(:party).where( party: { type: "Party::Vendor" } ) }
scope :of_customers, -> { joins(:party).includes(:party).where( party: { type: "Party::Customer" } ) }
```

But get error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "party"
LINE 1: ...parties"."id" = "party_contacts"."party_id" WHERE "party"."t...
```

Comment: `where( party: ` should be plural

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Swards, I figured it out just a while before. The scope should be as follows:

```
scope :of_vendors, -> { joins(:party).includes(:parties).where( parties: { type: "Party::Vendor" } ) }
scope :of_customers, -> { joins(:party).includes(:parties).where( parties: { type: "Party::Customer" } ) }
```

It constructs right query:

```
2.4.0 :042 > PartyContact.of_vendors
PartyContact Load (8.8ms)  SELECT "party_contacts".* FROM "party_contacts" INNER JOIN "parties" ON "parties"."id" = "party_contacts"."party_id" WHERE "parties"."type" = $1  [["type", "Party::Vendor"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
2.4.0 :043 > PartyContact.of_customers
PartyContact Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "party_contacts".* FROM "party_contacts" INNER JOIN "parties" ON "parties"."id" = "party_contacts"."party_id" WHERE "parties"."type" = $1  [["type", "Party::Customer"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Here `party` is singular in `joins(:party)` as it is belongs_to relation. And `parties` is plural in `includes(:parties)` and `where(parties:{...})` as it is name of table.

Comment: Weird that `includes(:parties)` works.  It should only allow named associations.  It looks like it may be ignoring it.